# How to detect a GameKit Auto-Match failure

Tags: iphone, ios, game-center

How do you detect if a GameKit auto-match fails?

After 2 minutes of waiting, *GKMatchmakerViewControllerDelegate matchmakerViewController:didFindMatch:* is called even when no players were found with auto-match.  The Game Center trumpet sound even plays.  I'm certain that no players are actually found because this is occurring in Game Center Sandbox where noone else has access to my app.

When I try loading the players*, I get an error, but there must be a better way to check for an auto match failure, right?  And is there a way to prevent the trumpet sound from triumphantly playing when auto-match failed?

---

*Loading the players shows an error when automatch fails:

```
[GKPlayer loadPlayersForIdentifiers:self.match.playerIDs withCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *players, NSError *error)
     {
         LOG_DEBUG(@"loadPlayersForIdentifiers completion handler called");
         if (error != nil)
         {
             LOG_ERROR(@"Error loading player information: %@", error);                 
         }
     }];
```

This shows the following error:

> Error loading player information: Error Domain=GKErrorDomain Code=17 "The requested operations could not be completed because one or more parameters are invalid." UserInfo=0xb183a70 {NSLocalizedDescription=The requested operations could not be completed because one or more parameters are invalid.}

---

Here is the code I'm using to bring up the GameKit match user interface:

```
GKMatchRequest *request = [[GKMatchRequest alloc] init];
request.minPlayers = 2;
request.maxPlayers = 2;
request.defaultNumberOfPlayers = 2;

GKMatchmakerViewController *mmvc = [[GKMatchmakerViewController alloc] initWithMatchRequest:request];
mmvc.matchmakerDelegate = self;

[self presentViewController:mmvc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

---

For full context, my entire app is open source and the main view controller is here: https://github.com/jdimatteo/TeamRun/blob/master/TeamRun/TeamRun/TeamRunViewController.m

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Auto-match will succeed even when it hasn't found a player. The second (and so forth) participants will be non-nil objects with nil ID and represent place holders for matching in future players. This lets the game begin immediately if the first turn can be taken without having all the players added to the game.

I imagine the error from loadPlayersWithIdentifiers is because some of those identifiers are nil.

You could check for `participant.playerID == nil` and either treat that as if the match is not ready yet or handle it in whatever way makes sense for your game.

Answer (score 1):

[webjprgm's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18347679/960691) relates to `GKTurnBaseMatches` only, AFAIK. From the look of your code you're implementing a real-time match.

In real-time matches, auto-matching is only *kind of* guaranteed to succed.

I mean, in practice, I find it sometimes doesn't succeed at all. But other times it *returns an empty match.* By "empty" I mean that it will not have any players *at all*, not even the "non-nil objects with nil ID" referred to by wbjprgm, not even *you*.

The tricky bit is that, if you get returned an empty match, *sometimes* that match will actually get filled soon after. But only sometimes. Other times you can wait around forever and it doesn't get filled.

So in order to monitor this situation, what I've had to do is complicated, but it works:

- In your request handler, store any returned `GKMatch` as an instance variable. I'm sure you already do this.
- After sending off your request, create a `DispatchSourceTimer` that runs a task after 15 seconds or so*. `DispatchSourceTimer` is available in Swift, the same thing is doable but more complicated in Objective-C.
- That timer *must run in the background thread.* This is very important. This will not work in a high-priority queue.
- In that task, check two things.

  - Check for that `GKMatch` instance variable being `nil`.
  - If it's not `nil`, check for its `.players.count` number being `0`.
- *If the first condition is true,* cancel the match request, and in the cancellation's completion handler, start a new request and a new timer.
- *If the second condition is true*, do the same thing, except this time set the timer to go off in 20 seconds (because sometimes it takes a little longer for an existing match to get filled, but you still don't want to hang around forever).

The end result is that you have a looping cycle of requesting an auto-match, checking if it's succeeded, and cancelling and re-starting the request if it hasn't.

It took me a long time to make this solution work, but when I did, I was very happy with the results. Yes, it's a complicated process, and if anyone wants to try it, I wish them the best of luck navigating the many pitfalls of both Game Kit and Grand Central Dispatch.

But it's worth mentioning that in my tests to date, *this has never failed* to match two players requesting an auto-matched game. Before I did this, it was a frequent occurance that two players requesting a game would never connect. For me, it works really well.

*note: *I have found that setting the timer for any less than 15 seconds makes it extremely unlikely that the process will succeed.* Not totally sure why, but that's the case.